# Using stored procedures in SQL Server to get data for ASP.NET: where from another table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to use a stored procedure (SQL Server Management Studio) to get data from a table. My problem is, that I need a where clause from another table to filter.

I need the availability for an item from table A. When my page is accessed, a stored procedure is used to retrieve an item_no. How can I then use that item_no to find the availability in table A?

Table A:

```
item_avail_no| availability | ...
```

Stored procedure: `SP_GetExternalStock`

Table B:

```
item_No | ...
```

Stored procedure: `SP_GetItemDetails`

I would then like to display that availability in ASP.NET using a literal.

Thanks in advance!

SQL:

```
SELECT availability 
FROM TableA
WHERE item_no = item_avail_no
```

ASP:

```
<%If lExternalStorage.Text = "" Then %>
  <div class="row" id="extstorage">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <strong>External Storage</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
     <asp:Literal ID="lExternalStorage" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </div>
<%End If%>
```

**Edit:**

A thought I had: can I "exec" the `GetItemDetails` in my stored procedure and then get the item_no there? Or is said item_no already available somehow?

On the website I have a row item_no, some other stuff and then the external storage

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question. Please post full table description and example data for each table, describe how the tables link together and tell us what data your stored procedures will take in and should return

Comment: Sorry if I didn't give enough information. I Have worked on this for a while now and I seem to have figured out the first step. The exact question would be: How can I retrieve data from a SQL Table to then show as a literal in ASP.NET. Thanks for looking over it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have found the answer on my own:

I already had a Stored Procedure to retrieve data. I created a Function where I return the availability for an item, if the product numbers match.

Thanks for the tips!

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MYFUNC_FN_GetExternalStorage_Base] 
(

    @No as nvarchar(20)

)
RETURNS int     

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnVar as int

    set @ReturnVar = isnull( (SELECT TOP 1  verfuegbar
                     FROM TABLE_A
                     WHERE @No = ItemNo), '0')

    RETURN @ReturnVar

END
```